# How to do proper performance testing and analysis of alacritty and zsh

Tags: performance, terminal, zsh, perf, alacritty

I've been working with my setup lately and have been trying to determine where my 2.3s terminal load times have been coming from. I'm fairly new to linux performance testing in general but I have determined a few things.

The first thing I should mention is that `terminal` is a shell program with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

WINIT_X11_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5 alacritty "$@"
```

The stats on launching the terminal program (alacritty) and its shell (zsh -l):

```
> perf stat -r 10 -d terminal -e $SHELL -slc exit

 Performance counter stats for 'terminal -e /usr/bin/zsh -slc exit' (10 runs):

            602.55 msec task-clock                       #    0.261 CPUs utilized            ( +-  1.33% )
               957      context-switches                 #    1.532 K/sec                    ( +-  0.42% )
                92      cpu-migrations                   #  147.298 /sec                     ( +-  1.89% )
            68,150      page-faults                      #  109.113 K/sec                    ( +-  0.13% )
     2,188,445,151      cycles                           #    3.504 GHz                      ( +-  0.17% )
     3,695,337,515      instructions                     #    1.70  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.08% )
       791,333,786      branches                         #    1.267 G/sec                    ( +-  0.06% )
        14,007,258      branch-misses                    #    1.78% of all branches          ( +-  0.09% )
    10,893,173,535      slots                            #   17.441 G/sec                    ( +-  0.13% )
     3,574,546,556      topdown-retiring                 #     30.5% Retiring                ( +-  0.11% )
     2,888,937,632      topdown-bad-spec                 #     24.0% Bad Speculation         ( +-  0.41% )
     3,125,577,758      topdown-fe-bound                 #     27.1% Frontend Bound          ( +-  0.16% )
     2,189,183,796      topdown-be-bound                 #     18.4% Backend Bound           ( +-  0.47% )
       924,852,782      L1-dcache-loads                  #    1.481 G/sec                    ( +-  0.07% )
        38,308,478      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    4.16% of all L1-dcache accesses  ( +-  0.09% )
         3,445,566      LLC-loads                        #    5.517 M/sec                    ( +-  0.20% )
           725,990      LLC-load-misses                  #   20.97% of all LL-cache accesses  ( +-  0.36% )

           2.30683 +- 0.00331 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  0.14% )
```

The stats on launching just the shell (zsh):

```
 Performance counter stats for '/usr/bin/zsh -i -c exit' (10 runs):

          1,548.56 msec task-clock                       #    0.987 CPUs utilized            ( +-  3.28% )
               525      context-switches                 #  323.233 /sec                     ( +- 21.17% )
                16      cpu-migrations                   #    9.851 /sec                     ( +- 11.33% )
            90,616      page-faults                      #   55.791 K/sec                    ( +-  2.63% )
     6,559,830,564      cycles                           #    4.039 GHz                      ( +-  3.18% )
    11,317,955,247      instructions                     #    1.68  insn per cycle           ( +-  3.69% )
     2,351,473,571      branches                         #    1.448 G/sec                    ( +-  3.46% )
        46,539,165      branch-misses                    #    1.91% of all branches          ( +-  1.31% )
    32,783,001,655      slots                            #   20.184 G/sec                    ( +-  3.18% )
    10,776,867,769      topdown-retiring                 #     32.5% Retiring                ( +-  3.28% )
     5,729,353,491      topdown-bad-spec                 #     18.2% Bad Speculation         ( +-  6.90% )
    11,083,567,578      topdown-fe-bound                 #     33.3% Frontend Bound          ( +-  2.34% )
     5,458,201,823      topdown-be-bound                 #     15.9% Backend Bound           ( +-  4.51% )
     3,180,211,376      L1-dcache-loads                  #    1.958 G/sec                    ( +-  3.10% )
       126,282,947      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    3.85% of all L1-dcache accesses  ( +-  2.37% )
        14,347,257      LLC-loads                        #    8.833 M/sec                    ( +-  1.48% )
         2,386,047      LLC-load-misses                  #   16.33% of all LL-cache accesses  ( +-  0.77% )

            1.5682 +- 0.0550 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  3.51% )
```

The stats on launching the shell (zsh) with `zmodload zsh/zprof`:

```
num  calls                time                       self            name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1)   31          78.54     2.53   77.09%     50.07     1.62   49.14%  antigen
 2)    2          23.24    11.62   22.81%     15.93     7.96   15.63%  compinit
 3)    2           7.31     3.66    7.18%      7.31     3.66    7.18%  compaudit
 4)    1           8.27     8.27    8.12%      7.29     7.29    7.16%  _autoenv_source
 5)    1           6.93     6.93    6.80%      6.93     6.93    6.80%  detect-clipboard
 6)    1           5.18     5.18    5.08%      5.18     5.18    5.08%  _autoenv_hash_pair
 7)    1           2.49     2.49    2.45%      2.45     2.45    2.41%  _zsh_highlight_load_highlighters
 8)    2           1.01     0.51    0.99%      1.01     0.51    0.99%  _autoenv_stack_entered_contains
 9)   10           0.91     0.09    0.89%      0.91     0.09    0.89%  add-zsh-hook
10)    1           0.94     0.94    0.92%      0.87     0.87    0.85%  _autoenv_stack_entered_add
11)    1           0.85     0.85    0.84%      0.85     0.85    0.84%  async_init
12)    1           0.49     0.49    0.49%      0.49     0.49    0.48%  _zsh_highlight__function_callable_p
13)    1           0.45     0.45    0.44%      0.45     0.45    0.44%  colors
14)    3           0.38     0.13    0.37%      0.35     0.12    0.35%  add-zle-hook-widget
15)    6           0.34     0.06    0.34%      0.34     0.06    0.34%  is-at-least
16)    2          15.14     7.57   14.86%      0.27     0.13    0.26%  _autoenv_chpwd_handler
17)    1           5.46     5.46    5.36%      0.26     0.26    0.26%  _autoenv_authorized_env_file
18)    1           0.23     0.23    0.22%      0.23     0.23    0.22%  regexp-replace
19)   11           0.19     0.02    0.19%      0.19     0.02    0.19%  _autoenv_debug
20)    2           0.10     0.05    0.10%      0.10     0.05    0.10%  wrap_clipboard_widgets
21)   16           0.09     0.01    0.09%      0.09     0.01    0.09%  compdef
22)    1           0.08     0.08    0.08%      0.08     0.08    0.08%  (anon) [/home/nate-wilkins/.antigen/bundles/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh:458]
23)    2           0.05     0.02    0.05%      0.05     0.02    0.05%  bashcompinit
24)    1           0.06     0.06    0.06%      0.04     0.04    0.04%  _autoenv_stack_entered_remove
25)    1           5.50     5.50    5.40%      0.03     0.03    0.03%  _autoenv_check_authorized_env_file
26)    1           0.04     0.04    0.04%      0.03     0.03    0.03%  complete
27)    1           0.88     0.88    0.87%      0.03     0.03    0.03%  async
28)    1           0.03     0.03    0.02%      0.03     0.03    0.02%  (anon) [/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/add-zle-hook-widget:28]
29)    2           0.01     0.00    0.01%      0.01     0.00    0.01%  env_default
30)    1           0.01     0.01    0.01%      0.01     0.01    0.01%  _zsh_highlight__is_function_p
31)    1           0.00     0.00    0.00%      0.00     0.00    0.00%  _zsh_highlight_bind_widgets
```

Lastly I have a `perf` run with a corresponding flamegraph:

`perf-run --out alacritty --command "terminal -e $SHELL -slc exit"`

[image]

But I'm not sure how to interpret the flamegraph since it seems to have everything in it and not just the command that was run.

So my question is:
What is taking up the most time in my terminal setup and is there another approach I could use to better determine where the problem is coming from?

Comment: It is certainly a good idea to use a perf record+report with a call-graph so to see why the target functions (mainly `antigen` and `compinit`) are slow. You should get the part of the assembly code that are hot. If you build zsh with the debugging information, then you can also know approximately which part of the source code cause the performance issue (note this could also be useful to debug zsh: eg. possibly see the variable values). By the way, note that [antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen) related to zsh plugins. Maybe a plugin is the root of the performance issue.

Comment: There are few past related (closed) issues on the antigen project that it may be good to look: https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/359 https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/116 https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/28